# PHP Form Selected getting all values

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox

Can anyone help me understand when I var_dump the product id's I get an array of the last id and not all of them individually? It's cycling through all that is selected so should return the id value for each of them?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['feature'])){
    if(isset($_POST['test'])){
        foreach($_POST['test'] as $selected){
            $option = 'No';
            var_dump($row['product_id']);
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php
    $query = $products->findAll();
    foreach($query as $row){
        if($row['featured'] == 'Yes'){
            echo "<label for='featured'>" . $row['p_name'] . " </label> <input type='checkbox' name='test[]' value ='Yes'checked>
            <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='" . $row['product_id'] . "'>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<label for='featured'>" . $row['p_name'] . " </label> <input type='checkbox' name='test[]' value ='No'>
            <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='" . $row['product_id'] . "'>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="feature" value="Feature">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put the `var_dump` outside of the loop?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Yeah, still get an array of only the last id

Comment: i think u should use `var_dump($selected['product_id']);`

Comment: @shajji Getting an error of Illegal string offset

Comment: at which line ?

Comment: just do this var_dump($selected);

Comment: yup @ShanteshwarInde is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the `var_dump` inside foreach, try it outside the foreach loop!

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['feature'])){
      if(isset($_POST['test'])){
        foreach($_POST['test'] as $selected){
        $option = 'No';
        $res = $selected['product_id'];
        }
        }
        var_dump($res);
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: Getting illegal string offset on line 6

Comment: @JackS `echo $selected['product_id'];` and what do you see?

Comment: Illegal string offset 'product_id'

Comment: @JackS go back a little and do `echo $row['product_id'];` in your `foreach($query as $row){` and what do you get?

Comment: I get an array of product id's that are selected, although the ID is the same and not the individual ID's for each selected item.